# Where could this green residue that is clogging fixture screens be coming from?

Tags: plumbing

I have a big problem with green residue clogging fixture screens. There has been no recent(for the last 2 years) plumbing work in the house so it is not flux/solder residue. I have two 50 gallon tanks in series. It appears much worse on the hot water side. I am beginning to think it is a recirculation line coming of the second tank. Because that line's supply comes from the bottom of the tank I think it may be spreading settled matter from the tank.

Thoughts/Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Green clogs in fine filters is usually due to algae being sucked up from the bottom of a holding tank. This is not uncommon in a water heater. This is a good reason to drain holding tanks annually to get rid of sediments. Also a good reason to never use water from a water heater to cook with. A water heater that is set below 130 degrees F is a breading ground for bacteria if not cycled often or allowed to set unused for several days at a time. (like when away on vacation) It could be copper oxide, but that would be very uncommon unless you have copper holding tanks.